# Show post description in the posts page - LawPlus Theme wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

My Wordpress site uses the LawPlus theme and it does not show the post description under each post block in the posts page (which shows all posts as a grid). The following source only shows the title and the image but no way to display a few lines/words from the post.

**/wp-content/themes/lawplus/default-templates/page.php**

```
<?php
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>
    <div class="page-detail-wrapper">
        <?php echo lawplus_show_title( '<h1 class="title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
        <?php lawplus_post_detail_thumbnail(); ?>
        <div class="entry-content">
            <?php
                the_content( '<a href="%s" class="read-more">%s<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>',
                    esc_url( get_permalink() ),
                    esc_html__( 'Read more', 'lawplus' ) );

                wp_link_pages( array(
                    'before' => '<div class="page-links"><span class="page-links-title">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'lawplus' ) . '</span>',
                    'after' => '</div>',
                    'link_before' => '<span>',
                    'link_after' => '</span>',
                ) );
            ?>
        </div>
        <footer class="entry-footer">
            <?php edit_post_link( esc_html__( 'Edit', 'lawplus' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <?php
        if ( comments_open() ) :
            comments_template();
        endif;
    ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: put get_the_excerpt() function just below thumbnail function

Comment: @Aki no, it didn't work

Comment: The `the_content()` function that's already there should do it. Is it a custom post type?

Comment: @Shoelaced I guess so. I have no idea where that is located to make any changes.

Comment: Also if you mean the main list of blog posts, it might not be using `page.php`. See if there's a `home.php` somewhere and if not, look at the `index.php`.

Comment: can you let's us know the theme directory architect with file name. Is there any specific file for the content. Are you that your page is rendering the from this code only?